# Trying to use an integer in a WHERE clause

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I'm trying to use an integer value in a WHERE clause (looking at an integer field).

```
expression = "'SERVICE' = 'Service' "
expression = expression + 'AND '
expression = expression + "'GPS_TIME_TOTAL' > " + "%d" % 10
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(outServFCView,"NEW_SELECTION",expression)
```

This code (using the %d) gives me 'ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression'

When I use %s and '', it runs OK but doesn't give me any records because it's looking into a integer field to find a string.

```
'SERVICE' = 'Service' AND 'GPS_TIME_TOTAL' > '10'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post your solution as an answer to your question(then mark it). so it can help people who faces the same problem.

Comment: Aragon is suggesting that instead of editing your question with the solution, paste the solution into "Your Answer", then mark that answer as accepted. This way future readers will know what worked, and won't confuse the solution with the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I built it up in Arcmap and got the python snippit... turns out using docstring will work

```
expression = expression + '''"GPS_TIME_TOTAL" < 15'''
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
sql = '"SERVICE" = \'Service\' AND "GPS_TIME_TOTAL" > %d' % 10
```